# TFS 2015 : Test run is aborted in RunTest functional task

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2015  to run our orderedtests. It is aborting after 1 hour.We have modified the testSettings file runtimeout value.Orderetest timeout value also.Still no use it is still failing after running 1 hour.Test Agent is not there.

As we are new to visual studio online we are not able to understand what is the issue.

Following are the log files of the tasks in the build definition.:

Deploy TestAgent log file:

> 2017-08-01T08:28:50.0146249Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy TestAgent on test machines
>   2017-08-01T08:28:50.0771279Z Preparing task execution handler.
>   2017-08-01T08:28:50.5302568Z Executing the powershell script: D:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\DeployTestAgent.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7645941Z DistributedTests: Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Inputs provided are:
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Username: ingrnet\spel-daily-build
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Use HTTP Port: True
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Run as process: True
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Login Automatically: True
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Disable Screen saver: True
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Agent would be downloaded from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Update test agent: False
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Path to script that installs test agent on remote machine: D:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\TestAgentInstall.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Path to script that configures test agent on remote machine: D:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Path to script that downloads test agent on azure remote machines : D:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\DownloadTestAgent.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is installed on remote machine: D:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\CheckTestAgentInstallation.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is already running on remote machine: D:\agent_work_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\VerifyTestMachinesAreInUse.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.7802207Z DistributedTests: Path to script that helps to download and configure test agent : 
>   2017-08-01T08:28:52.8583806Z DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' on machine 'ISRVEL2018YS1.ingrnet.com:5985' is being run
>   2017-08-01T08:29:15.9362386Z DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' on machine 'ISRVEL2018YS1.ingrnet.com:5985' completed.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:15.9518654Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: You may be using machine 'ISRVEL2018YS1.ingrnet.com:5985' across one or more concurrent builds. This is currently not supported. Use an unique machine per build definition and ensure there are no concurrent builds In Progress from any given build definition using a machine.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:15.9518654Z DistributedTests: Update test agent is disabled. Skipping test agent updates.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:15.9518654Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ISRVEL2018YS1.ingrnet.com:5985' is being run
>   2017-08-01T08:29:40.3266525Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'ISRVEL2018YS1.ingrnet.com:5985' completed.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:40.3266525Z DistributedTests: Testagents are configured and ready to run tests, make sure you use the 'Visual Studio Test using Test Agent' task in the Build Definition after this task.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:40.4047477Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy TestAgent on test machines

We are trying to run set of tests using 3 tasks.
1st Run Functional Test Task log file:

> 2017-08-01T08:29:40.4047477Z ##[section]Starting: Run first batch of tests
>   2017-08-01T08:29:40.8734851Z Preparing task execution handler.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:41.2953631Z Executing the powershell script: D:\agent_work_tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent_d353d6a2-e361-4a8f-8d8c-123bebb71028\1.0.49\RunDistributedTests.ps1
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.4047175Z DistributedTests: Environment WinRm Protocol HTTP.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.4203434Z DistributedTests: Run Settings File Path : D:\agent_work\2\s\SUIT\SmartPlantElectrical\Tests\SPELSanityTestSuite\SanityTests\SanityTests.testsettings
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: SourceFilter: **\sanitytests_a.orderedtest TestCaseFilter: 
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: Run title: TestRun_SPEL2018-SUIT_82465
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: is automated: True
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: test settings id : 6263
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: build location: C:\SUITinstallation\AUTs\SmartPlantElectrical\Tests\SPELSanityTestSuite\SanityTests
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: build id: 82465
>   2017-08-01T08:29:43.7953324Z DistributedTests: test configuration mapping: 
>   2017-08-01T08:29:44.3422159Z DistributedTests: Test Run with Id 89461 Queued
>   2017-08-01T08:29:44.7953194Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T08:29:55.2327218Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T08:30:05.6544901Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T08:30:16.1387782Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T08:30:26.5605373Z DistributedTests: Please use this link to analyze the test run : https://ppmtfs.intergraph.com/tfs/PPMCOL/PPM/_TestManagement/Runs#_a=resultQuery&runId=89461&queryPath=Recent+Run%2FRun+89461
>   2017-08-01T08:30:26.5605373Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T08:30:26.5605373Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 1, Passed Tests : 0
>   2017-08-01T10:18:12.5264158Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:12.5264158Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 1, Passed Tests : 0
>   2017-08-01T10:18:22.9481786Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'InProgress' state.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:22.9481786Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 1, Passed Tests : 0
>   2017-08-01T10:18:33.4012032Z DistributedTests: Test run '89461' is in 'Aborted' state.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:33.4012032Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 1, Passed Tests : 0
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.4167230Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: New test run created.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z Test Run queued for Project Build Service.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z 
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Completed . Test run id : 89461
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: 1 test cases discovered.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test execution started. Test run id : 89461
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : One or more errors occurred.--->The HTTP request timed out after 00:01:40.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z 
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 89461
>   2017-08-01T10:18:43.8542042Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:44.1354528Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
>   2017-08-01T10:18:44.1354528Z ##[section]Finishing: Run first batch of tests

Rest of the build not running after this.

Comment: What's the result if you manually run your orderedtests in your local environment? This will narrow down the issue is related to your testSettings  or tfs side.

Comment: Yes it is running completely if I run Orderedtest individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Unfortunately, Ordered tests are currently **not supported** with the **Run Functional Test task**. You can use the **Visual Studio test task** for running Ordered tests. More details and workaround please refer this threads: [Ordered test support in Run Functional Tests task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1923)

---

Since you are using three Run Functional Test Task. First you need to add "**Deploy Visual studio test agent**" task before every Run Functional Test task.

If the test agent is already installed, it will configure the test agent. but it's **mandatory** to add before Run Functional test task.

Your build definition should look like

```
Deploy test agent
Run Functional Tests
Deploy Test agent
Run functional tests task
...
```

Also  set "**Build job timeout in minutes**" setting with 0 value at Build Definition. The default value is 60 minutes, just the same time limitation in your case. The root cause of the issue maybe just this with serious doubts.

[image]

An empty or zero value indicates an infinite timeout.

Comment: I added "Deploy Visual studio test agent"  task before each Run Functional task. 
now all the three ordered tests are running,but  at the end of each ordered test I am again  seeing "Abort" message.

Comment: Error : Some tests could not run because all test agents of this testrun were unreachable for long time. Ensure that all testagents are able to communicate with the server and retry again.
2017-08-02T11:05:54.9947973Z 
2017-08-02T11:05:54.9947973Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 89772

Comment: @NAGASREE Did you set  "**Build job timeout in minutes**" setting with 0 value at Build Definition - General ?

Comment: Yes I have set "Build job timeout in minutes" setting with 0 value at Build Definition.

Comment: @NAGASREE  Unfortunately, Ordered tests are currently **not supported** with the Run Functional Test task. You can use the Visual Studio test task for running Ordered tests. More details and workaround please refer this threads: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1923